# How to draw a Button like rectangle with text in Android Canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-view, android-canvas

In Android app , I want to draw a button in canvas , like the image exactly the below image

[image: campsitebutton]

I tried some stack overflow answers but can't get the exact output , particularly the light shadow below . My worst code is below

```
        val corners = floatArrayOf(
                80f, 80f,   // Top left radius in px
                80f, 80f,   // Top right radius in px
                0f, 0f,     // Bottom right radius in px
                0f, 0f      // Bottom left radius in px
        )

        val path = Path()
        val rect = RectF(550f, 500f, 100f, 300f)

        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL;
        paint.color = Color.WHITE;
        path.addRoundRect(rect, corners, Path.Direction.CW)
        canvas?.drawPath(path, paint)

        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE;
        paint.color = Color.BLACK;
        path.addRoundRect(rect, corners, Path.Direction.CW)
        canvas?.drawPath(path, paint)

        paint.setColor(Color.RED)
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL)
        val paint2 = Paint()
        paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN)
        paint2.setTextSize(50f) //set text size

        val w: Float = paint2.measureText("VIEW CAMPSITE MAP") / 2
        val textSize: Float = paint2.textSize
        canvas?.drawText("VIEW CAMPSITE MAP", 300f, 300f ,paint2);
```

Also I can't set text in correct position

I also need a gradient to show bulging state like a real material button

And also  need an click listener in the canvas / paint

I need it in pure canvas and paint  not in any views

please help me

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the ways. Dont forget to move all variables like text, textSize, etc in [custom attributes](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr). Also I didnt get what do you mean by "click listener in the canvas"

[image]

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
      ) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

//constants. move them all to custom attributes
private val boxRadius = convertDpToPixel(10f)
private val boxColor = Color.parseColor("#52618e")
private val boxBackgroundColor = Color.WHITE
private val boxShadowSize = convertDpToPixel(2f)
private val boxStrokeWidth = convertDpToPixel(1f)
private val textColor = Color.parseColor("#21a207")
private val fontSize = convertDpToPixel(30f)
private val text = "View Campsite Plan"

private lateinit var boxShadow: RectF
private lateinit var boxBackground: RectF
private lateinit var boxShadowPaint: Paint
private lateinit var boxBackgroundPaint: Paint
private var textWidth = 0f
private var textSmallGlyphHeight = 0f
private lateinit var textPaint: Paint

  override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
    boxShadow = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
    boxBackground = RectF(boxStrokeWidth, boxStrokeWidth,
        w.toFloat()-boxStrokeWidth, h.toFloat()-boxStrokeWidth-boxShadowSize)
    boxShadowPaint = Paint().apply { color = boxColor }
    boxBackgroundPaint = Paint().apply { color = boxBackgroundColor }
    textPaint = Paint().apply {
        color = textColor
        textSize = fontSize
        typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
        textWidth = measureText(text)
        textSmallGlyphHeight = fontMetrics.run { ascent + descent }
    }
  }

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    canvas?.drawRoundRect(boxShadow, boxRadius, boxRadius, boxShadowPaint)
    canvas?.drawRoundRect(boxBackground, boxRadius, boxRadius, boxBackgroundPaint)
    val textStartPadding = (width - textWidth)/2f
    val textTopPadding = (height - textSmallGlyphHeight)/2f
    canvas?.drawText(text, textStartPadding, textTopPadding, textPaint)
  }

  private fun convertDpToPixel(dp: Float) =
    dp*(resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi/DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
}
```

Comment: I think they just want to set a click listener on the view, probably on the part that has the button drawn on it. Your solution fills the view's canvas so that's all good, but if they're trying to draw a bunch of buttons on one canvas they'll need some kind of "what part did the user touch" logic in the click listener

Comment: Okay then It makes sense to create `List<Rect>` of all buttons placed on canvas and register `GestureDetector` with `onSingleTapUp` which gets `x` and `y` coordinates of click and checks which button from that list was triggered in this coordinate.